# Remove an assembly from the path of T4 generator in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

In my project I have Resharper installed, and I'm doing design time templating with T4 Templates from within Visual Studio.

I have

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDIr)FTest\bin\Debug\FTest.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDIr)FTest\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll" #>
```

I also have

```
<#@ import namespace="NUnit.Framework" #>
```

Then i have a cast in the code like this

```
    <#
    var someVar = (TestAttribute)typeof(BaseTest).GetMethods()
    .Where(
    x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(y => y.Name == "CategoryAttribute" && ((CategoryAttribute)y).Name == "Smoke").Any()
     )
    #>
```

Im getting an invalid cast exception. It tells me that the template generator uses a different 'nunit.framework' dll than the project dll uses.

```
Error   21  Running transformation: System.InvalidCastException: [A]NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute cannot be cast to [B]NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute. Type A originates from 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Users\Chandirasekar Thiaga\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\ZGE1068O.OD1\ARWGXOXD.EMZ\7407d57d\ff3a4298_6ceccc01\nunit.framework.dll'. Type B originates from 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.1\Bin\nunit.framework.dll'.
```

How do I, when importing with <#@ import namespace="NUnit.Framework" #> import the same dll as the one that FTest.dll uses?  I do not want to use the Resharper's version of nunit!

EDIT :

After setting registry key like GarethJ said, the message looks like this :

```
Error   12  Running transformation: System.InvalidCastException: [A]NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute cannot be cast to [B]NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute. Type A originates from 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Repos\BSF-Functional-Automation\FunctionalTest\FunctionalTest\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll'. Type B originates from 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.1\Bin\nunit.framework.dll'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating64EAA000670725A96AF52252D093BE63.GeneratedTextTransformation.<TransformText>b__5(Object x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating64EAA000670725A96AF52252D093BE63.GeneratedTextTransformation.<TransformText>b__4(MethodInfo m)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating64EAA000670725A96AF52252D093BE63.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)        1   1
```

Comment: Can you try turning off assembly caching temporarily please, so we get cleaner data in the exception.  This shoudl remove the temp assembly idrectory under appdata and let us see which two assemblies we're really comparing, then we can try to work out where resharper's directory is getting pulled in.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TextTemplating

Set the string value ShadowCopy=false

Comment: Done. It now shows the Uncached DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @import just contributes a 'using' statement rather than a reference, so it's not consequential here.

Type A loaded in the LoadFrom context is the one that is being loaded by the assembly tag in T4.
Type B that's coming from the Resharper directory appears from this error to be coming from the reflection over the assembly that's containing 'BaseTest'.

I'd try looking at the build of BaseTest to see if Resharper could have crept in here.  You can probably validate this theory by running reflector or ildasm over basetest's assembly.

Comment: `((CategoryAttribute)y)` In this segment, I felt `y` is Type A and `CategoryAttribute` is Type B and we are trying to cast A to B. The message says Type B originates from Resharper's Nunit which tells me that the text `CategoryAttribute` which I typed in the there is coming from Resharper, and the variable `y` is coming from BaseTest assembly.

Comment: If I type the code `OfType<CategoryAttribute>` (C# generics) or `(CategoryAttribute)y` in the T4 file and I want that also to use the nunit refered to by the BaseTest assembly. But unfortunately If I type the type-name in it picks up the wrong assembly type. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I fixed it temporarily by using reflection to get type throughout the template, and never handwriting a type name at all, except witihin strings - but please do help me understand how the T4 engine picks up some random DLL which is not referenced in the BaseTest DLL (Yes, the BaseTest project does not reference any resharper nunit) or mentioned using @assembly directive.

Comment: I don't have Resharper to hand to try, but it could be that the resharper nunit has been added to the probing path in devenv.exe.config by Resharper's installation.  That would probably cause T4 to find that first when doing a basic resolve for the indirect use of a type.

Comment: Resharper did add its nUnit Dll to devenv config - Thanks!